# Suggested edit looks ok, but there is an emoji: should I edit or reject + edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In the review queue, I stumbled on a suggested edit that I'm unsure about:

[image: Screenshot of suggested edit with emoji circled]

Excepted for the unicorn emoji inserted, this edit fixes the language, and I would have probably approved it.

But, because of the unicorn, and since we are not on Apr 1st, I think I should at least edit and remove it.

But should I *reject and edit*, or *improve edit* (awarding the small rep bonus, since the editor is low rep)?

Comment: It's Apr 1st somewhere on the world (hence the duck). But anyway as the content would not be auto-removed after Apr 1st it should not be there anyway.

Comment: Why not using improve? I mean, I think you will use too much time just applying the same changes that the edit is applying.

Comment: To be clearer, the question is whether I choose "Improve edit" or "reject and edit". The only difference would not be on my side, but on the side of the editor (whether he gains the small rep bonus and on a stat point of view). (question edited)

Comment: My opinion FWIW: "Improve edit" if that's the only change. But keep an eye out for the individual and further such "fun and games" (these things often appear in bunches) and alert a moderator if a lot of them show up.

Comment: @user202729 actually, it's *always* Apr 1st somewhere in the world. (and just in case someone doubts it, details and complete proof [can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7wFa.jpg)  for instance)

Comment: Reputation or not, the important thing is to let the editor know that it should not be done. _Who cares about reputation?_

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The case of the funny emoji falls into the "typo" category. That's true even on a 1st of April or 1st of January because once accepted it would be persistent.

When the edit is globally a good improvement, with only a minor typo (or emoji/small fluff), please choose "*Improve edit*" and simply fix the typo (remove emoji/fluff).

After that, if you feel like it, you can contact the editor with a comment on the same post, reminding him or her to be careful about the correctness of suggested edits. Then, once your comment was read, you delete it.